# Stored Procedure Replication or copying (SQL Server)

Tags: sql-server, stored-procedures, copy, replication

Is it posible to replicate or copy the stored procedure easy from one SQL Server to an other?

Answer (score 1):

yes you can do this : http://blog.sqlauthority.com/2009/07/29/sql-server-2008-copy-database-with-data-generate-t-sql-for-inserting-data-from-one-table-to-another-table/

Hope this will help you :)

Comment: Thanks, that's a good way to bulk-copy all the sprocs/functions.

Answer (score 1):

There are many ways of doing this as mentioned in [this excellent article](http://searchsqlserver.techtarget.com/tip/0,289483,sid87_gci1241182_mem1,00.html) -

- Native replication features;
- Log shipping;
- Manual deployments, and;
- Automated deployments and synchronization.

You'll need to create an account on the site, alternatively you can use username/passwords provided by [bugmenot](http://www.bugmenot.com/view/techtarget.com).

Answer (score 0):

yes, you can Data Transformation services to export/import the stored procedure.
or you can copy the syntax and execute it again on the other server